# Is "Lebesgue integral with respect to a discrete measure" a continuous functional?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\int \cdot d\mu$ be a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, where $\mu$ is a discrete measure. If I endow $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ with the topology of pointwise convergence, is $\int \cdot d\mu$ continuous? I feel that it should be true, since the limit and the integral are interchangeable in this case. But this does not imply continuity when the topology is not metrizable.

Comment: Just to be precise, I think your domain should be no larger than the set of $\mu$-integrable functions to keep the codomain as $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is the support of $\mu$ finite?